# Splitting each lines of a file in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a file which is like below:

```
AirGO:50
IndiGo:100
SpliceJet:30
JEt:50
SpiceJet:30
```

I want the output like :

```
50 100 30 50 30
```

I am trying to do as below:

```
awk -F ":" '{ printf "%d", $2}' file1.txt
```

The output I am getting is  like

```
50100305030
```

How Can I get my output like this?

```
50 100 30 50 30
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
$ cut -d: -f2 file1.txt | paste -d' ' -s
50 100 30 50 30
```

Or with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F: 'BEGIN{first=1}{printf (first ? "%d" : " %d"), $2; first=0}END{printf "\n"}' file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks..This is very helpful..But I have a small issue again here..I have 2 files..When I am using the cut coommand I am getting the output of 2 lines.But 2nd line is staring with a blank space.Could you please let me know the issue here.

Comment: Note you can use `print ""`, as an alternative to `printf "\n"`

Comment: To replace two and more spaces to just one you can add `| tr -s ' '` at the end of command above. Is this what you are looking for? If not, then could you post an example?

Answer (score 2):

One more way

```
awk -F: '{a=a?a" "$2:$2}END{print a}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use space after %d like below (it will lead to space at end which should be ok as its not in question i hope):

```
awk -F ":" '{ printf "%d ", $2}' test.txt
```

Comment: Look at my comment on the other answer identical to yours

Answer (score 1):

Simply add some space after your `int` in the `print` ;)

```
awk -F ":" '{ printf "%d ", $2}' file1.txt
```

Comment: Might want to add an end block as this will cause the prompt to start on the same line

Comment: @Jidder exactly. `END {print ""}` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

For tiny files (less then 100 lines) and for simple usage I may avoid to use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). It seems a little bit of overkill for me. It can be solved easily in pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

I assume there is only one ':' in each input file line and no space in them. If it is true the solution is very simple (only built-in commands are used, so no expensive `fork` and `exec` calls):

```
out=($(<file1.txt)); out=${out[@]#*:}
```

The result is in the `out` variable, which can be handy if you want to do something with the result inside [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). The result of `echo "'$out'"` is `'50 100 30 50 30'`.

As **Jidder** pointed out this version still `fork`s (I need some investigation why. I see no reason for that). But I found a slightly longer and really forkless (and even faster) solution. This actually prints out the result (I assumed that `~` is not in the input file):

```
read -d"~" -ra out <file1.txt; echo ${out[@]#*:}
```

If the input may contain white space then the solution could be

```
while read -r x; do out+=" ${x#*:}" done <file1.txt
out=${out:1}
```

or similarly

```
while IFS=: read -r x x; do out+=" $x"; done <file1.txt
out=${out:1}
```

I hope this helps a bit!

Comment: How is awk overkill for this in any way ?

Comment: @Jidder: 1st: bash solution is shorter :). At 2nd: awk is slower (for small files(!)) as it has to be executed (`fork` (actually `clone`) the original [tag:bash] and `exec` [tag:awk]. Both are fairly expensive for the OS). 3rd: I assume the result has to be used somehow. So it has to be put into an environment variable, so it would be put used as `out=$(awk...)` which adds another `fork` to open a pipe. All this can be spared.

Comment: 1st: My awk solution is shorter if you include the echo command you have to perform to output the data. 2nd try running mine and your command for a large file and tell me which is quicker, pretty sure it is awk. 3rd Thats just a wild assumption that OP has not even slightly hinted at.

Comment: Look at my update, credit where its due though, your answer is a single character shorter than mine, dunno if that makes up for the significant detriment to speed though.

Comment: @Jidder: You may be right if the file is larger. See the first 3 words in my answer! According to my measurements bellow 10 KiB [tag:bash] is faster. For larger file `awk` is MUCH faster! Anyhow `fork` and `exec` is expensive as a lot has to be done by the kernel so for simple tasks I try to reduce the number of external calls.

Comment: @Jidder: Nope. `$(<file)` is a shortcut for `$(cat file)`, but is does not exec `cat` at all (see `Command Substitution` part of man bash(1). Surprisingly `\`<file\`` also works), just opens the file. Check with `strace -f -o y.log ./y.s˛`. Only one PID is listed. ;) Anyway my version is still shorter if the result has to be printed:  `out=($(<file1.txt));echo ${out[@]#*:}` :))))

Comment: I know what the command does and isn't a shortcut for cat, the end result may be the same though. You  are still forking a subshell either way though. Also unless the file is below 5k,(which for lines round about as long  as OPs is about 400 lines)  and even then the speed increase is insignicant(1ms and only sometimes)then awk is considerably faster. Awk is definitely the superior option when parsing lines of a file. Yours is shorter though :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63485/discussion-between-truey-and-jidder).